# spring security with velocity?

Tags: spring, security, velocity

i have an application where the pages are not in jsp but velocity, and it isn't running with spring either... i want to integrate spring security to it, but i couldn't find any documentation... i searcher in the springsource documentation [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html), but I couldn't find what to do.Is it even possible to start with? if so, how can I do it?

I tried to prepare a spring-security-context.xml

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
 <http pattern="/app/template/Login.vm" security="none" />
<http  auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" >
 <form-login login-page="/app/template/Login.vm/" username-parameter="loginName" password-parameter="password"
                login-processing-url="/app/template/Login.vm"
                default-target-url="/app/template/Home.vm" />
 </http>
  <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="xx" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <user name="yy" password="456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

--thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing at all to stop you from using Spring Security to provide method-level security in a project that uses the Velocity template egine. The two technologies will play happily together. In fact, years ago, the original author, Ben Alex, used to tell students at training courses how much he preferred velocity over JSP.

If you wanted to the Spring MVC framework, it also supports Velocity as a template engine.

To give you some insights about Spring the core consists of the following:

- A design pattern - dependency injection
- A programming paradigm - aspect oriented programming

In providing some rails around the above, the core is very useful in its own right. It also serves as the foundation for other portfolio products like Spring MVC and Spring Security.

I highly recommend the book *Spring in Action*, for getting started.